# Biostar GF7050V-M7 working with linux?

Tags: linux, hardware-compatibility

Do you know if Biostar GF7050V-M7 motherboard works completely with linux?

Answer (score 2):

On the basis that it is completely standard and quite old (for technology) hardware, I would say you'd be completely safe with this.

The one problem you might have with this is picking the right driver for the onboard nvidia card. It's a GeForce 7050 and some people [have had problems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-180/+bug/425372) with it in the past. These issues may have been fixed now (it's been a couple of years) and there are pointers in that thread.

Everything else seems standard and should work out-the-box.